# GCC with -Werror and -Wno-error=unused does not work as expected

Tags: gcc, compiler-warnings, compiler-options

I always compile with *[-Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall) [-Wextra](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra) [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror)*.

However, many times as I do quick compile tests I need to ignore the [-Wunused](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunused) suite of errors. For various reasons, I want to see them as warnings and not errors while leaving all other warnings as errors.

- [-Wno-unused](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno-unused) of course doesn't display any warning, so it is not what I need.
- The one I thought is the solution [-Wno-error=unused](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno-error_003d) unfortunately doesn't seem to work (they are still reported as errors),
- Individually setting the flags (e.g., `-Wno-error=unused-variable`) works as expected (reported as warning only).

So is there a way to make them warnings while leaving `-Werror` without to specify all the suit of options `-Wno-error=unused-...` individually?
Is the behavior of `-Werro -Wno-error=unused` a bug?

GCC with -Werror and -Wno-error=unused

Answer (score 10):

No, there isn’t any way to turn them off at once.

`-Wunused` enables a list of options like:

- [-Wunused-function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunused-function)
- [-Wunused-label](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunused-label)
- [-Wunused-value](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunused-value)
- [-Wunused-variable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunused-variable)

And you should disable them one by one with the `Wno` option.